# How can I style a nav bar link as selected using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a nav bar that uses anchor links (the nav bar is fixed and the user stays on one page). By default, I'd like to have the first link in the nav bar styled with a background highlight to indicate it has been selected. If the user clicks on a different link on the nav bar, I'd like that link to be given the selection styling instead.

Is there a pure HTML/CSS method to do this?

**Edit: I am currently tinkering with turning the nav links into secret radio buttons. I'll report back if I get it to work.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

```
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + a { 
  background: blue !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="x" name="selectedLink" checked />
<a href="#associatedAnchor1" onclick="document.getElementById('x').checked = true">
This is a link that will apply 'selected' style to itself and
strip the 'selected style from all other links in its group
</a>

<input type="radio" id="y" name="selectedLink" />
<a href="#associatedAnchor2" onclick="document.getElementById('y').checked = true">
This is a link that will apply 'selected' style to itself and
strip the 'selected style from all other links in its group
</a> <!-- and so on -->
```

It uses a *tiny* amount of JavaScript, but it's the closest thing to an answer that probably exists. Hope it's useful to somebody! :)

Comment: You don't need script, wrap each in a label and use this selector: `input[type="radio"]:checked ~ a`

Comment: This might raise some accessibility concerns as well.  People who use screen readers may be negatively impacted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :active Selector.

```
a:active { 
     background-color: yellow;
}
```

This style will be applied to the last element you clicked on... once you lose focus though, it will not retain the style.

It would be much better to just change the class via javascript if you can, in my opinion anyway.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a permanent state. The item would remain styled after being clicked. It's easy with JavaScript. I just wanted a non-JS-dependent approach if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:target` and style with that.  It would look something like:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #bada55;
}
#targetDiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #bada55;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
:target {
  background-color: purple !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#first" id="first">First</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#second" id="second">Second</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#third" id="third">Third</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#targetDiv">Target</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#targetDiv" id="targetDiv">Target Div</a><li>
</ul>
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/jjoL3wm0/).

**Note**
This will interfere with the browser history, so you may want to watch out for that.  It could also create a "jump", but if it's a fixed navigation you may be fine.  The fiddle has a `e.preventDefault()` on the links to prevent the jump, but I think you could be fine without it.

**UPDATED**

Added a fiddle and included targeting other `div`s as per the comment.

Comment: I'm wanting to target a scrollable div on the page, not the anchor link itself.

Comment: `:target` styles whatever is in the hash of the URL.  You could change the link to point to the `id` of the `div` you're wanting to style.  If you post your code in your question I can be more specific.

Comment: @Mike Updated the answer to include styling other `div`s.

Comment: It's meant to style the link but jump to the target anchor. In your code, the target is always the thing getting styled.

Comment: I think for that you're not going to be able to avoid JS.